# Ruby Geocoder Control Flow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to figure out how to set up the control flow for my index action using Geocoder and HTML5 Geolocation. Everything is working independently, just need to tie it all together. I need for my controller to work in this order

This should load automatically.
    `@locations = Location.near("27.961416, -82.445189", 1)`

Then if the user clicks the "Find My Location" button, which passes a hidden form to the controller it will render locations within two miles of them. Or if they use the search box, it will display the search results.

```
if  ([params[:lat], params[:lon]]).present?
  @locations = Location.near([params[:lat], params[:lon]], 2)
elsif params[:location].present?
  @locations = Location.near(params[:location], 2)
end
```

I've tried a few different combinations like the code below. It doesn't work, just there for reference of what I am going for. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def index
  if  ([params[:lat], params[:lon]]).present?
    @locations = Location.near([params[:lat], params[:lon]], 2)
  elsif params[:location].present?
    @locations = Location.near(params[:location], 2)
  end
  @locations = Location.near("27.961416, -82.445189", 1)  
end
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What is contained in `params[:lat]`, `params[:lon]`, and `params[:location]`? There's not enough information right now to help you.

Comment: Right, so the way it is set up above, the if elseif statement has no affect, it just loads `@locations = Location.near("27.961416, -82.445189", 1)` I can get the other parts to work with a different set up, but then another part will break. Do I need to create a separate search method maybe? It checks the conditions, neither exist and it just load the default @locations. When I click the button to "Find Me" or enter a search, it still doesn't work, which is what confuses me.